# Vertical scrolling but remove scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This has been asked several times across the internet; however, I can't get a solution that works for me. I need to maintain the ability to have vertical scrolling but hide the scrollbar from view at all times in the y direction.

I need my `#content-main` div to scroll independently from every other div. This works as is; however, I have a scrollbar I need to get rid of but I don't know how or why it is so difficult to do.

My code is set up like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="ipad"> 
        <div id="sidebar-main">
            <div id="logo-main">Title</div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="content-main">

            <div id="search-main">
                <div id="category-search">
                    <i id="hamburger-icon" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="auto loans" />
                    <i id="search-icon" class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="page-content">
                <img id="home-img" src="home-page.png" /> /* temp */
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS relevant for what I'm trying to do:

```
* {

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {

    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ipad {

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 768px;
    height: 1024px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content-main {

    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I've seen this "solution" but it does not work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/

And I've seen this but these did not work when applied to my `#content-main` div: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari.aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The key thing in the jsfiddle you linked is the `padding-right` property on the container2, which hides the scroll bar. Your problem is that you have a left menu which takes some space. You will have to work around your widths and add a `padding-right` to your `#content-main`.

Comment: The key to that is having an element (inner) inside another element (outer). The inner element needs to be larger than the outer element by the width of the scrollbar. In the outer element, you need to specifiy the height (e.g. 100%). Disable the horizontal scrolling of the inner element with ``overflow-x: hidden;`` and set the padding-right to the width of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I have given CSS for two div  separately #content-main div to scroll independently from every other div. And Should Close the DIV  of #ipad div  before start of #content-main div. here is the code of what you want.

```
<body>
<div id="ipad"> 
    <div id="sidebar-main">
        <div id="logo-main">Title</div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-option"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="content-main">
        <div id="search-main">
            <div id="category-search">
                <i id="hamburger-icon" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="auto loans" />
                <i id="search-icon" class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="page-content">
            <img id="home-img" src="home-page.png" /> /* temp */
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<style>
*{margin:0;}
#ipad{
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid green;
overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar-main{
 width: 100%;
height: 99%;
border: 1px solid blue;
overflow: auto;
padding-right: 15px;
}
#content-main{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid blue;
overflow: auto;
padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
height: 99%;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```